# Magento 2 Custom payment methods not display in backend new order create?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.6

I created a custom payment method and it is displaying in checkout page (frontend).But this payment method is not displayed in admin side also when i create a new order.
Anyone can help on this ?

My code..

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\Module\Model;  
class Net30 extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod  
{  
     protected $_code = 'net30'; 
     protected $_isOffline = true;
     protected $_canUseInternal  = true;
}
?>
```

> \app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\payment.xml

```
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Payment/etc/payment.xsd">  
    <groups>  
        <group id="offline">  
            <label>Offline Payment Methods</label>  
        </group>  
    </groups>  
    <methods>  
        <method name="net30">  
            <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>  
        </method>  
</methods>  
</payment>
```

> \app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
<section id="payment">  
            <group id="net30" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">  
                <label>Net30</label>  
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">  
                    <label>Enabled</label>  
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>  
                </field>  
                <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">  
                    <label>Title</label>  
                </field>  
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">  
                    <label>New Order Status</label>  
                    <source_model>Namespace\Module\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\Pendingpayment</source_model>  
                </field>  

                <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">  
                    <label>Payment from Applicable Countries</label>  
                    <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>  
                </field>  
                <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="41" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">  
                    <label>Payment from Specific Countries</label>  
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>  
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>  
                </field>  
                <field id="instructions" translate="label" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">  
                    <label>Instructions</label>  
                </field>  
                <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">  
                    <label>Sort Order</label>  
                    <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>  
                </field>  
            </group>
</section>  
    </system>
</config>
```

"\app\code\Namespace\Module\etc\config.xml"

1
                Net30
                processing_payment
                Instruction.
                true
                Namespace\Module\Model\Net30
        offline

Comment: paste your custom payment method code here.

Comment: post your code what you did , without this it's difficult to answer your question

Comment: Have you specified `can_use_internal` in payment `config.xml` (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/payment-option-config.html)?

Comment: @jonijones yes ..i specified this tag also

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat and Keyurshah, Updated my question..please any solution

Comment: do you have a config file? maybe that's the one you are missing.

Comment: no,added it in question also @magefms

Comment: You may need to define Block Class, the template and the layout to render your custom Payment module form in Admin panel order Creation page.
Please check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/formblocktype.html

Comment: i am writing the offline payment method.i think no need to extend the CC payment method.